# PHP Session variables disappearing on new page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, slim

First of all, I'm going to show my project directory in WampServer to understand my question. `app` is the application in PHP with Slim Framework, and maybe in the future it becomes a web service (no yet). The rest of files outside this folder are the web for the user:

[image: Project directory]

I'm working in PHP with session variables and Slim Framework. On page `login.php` I created two session variables. This file is not in Slim Framework app folder I'm doing.

This is the file `login.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION) && array_key_exists("sesionIniciada", $_SESSION)) {
    if ($_SESSION["sesionIniciada"] === true) {
        header('Location: /index.php');
    } else {
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION["LLAVE_ACCESO_WEB"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
        $_SESSION["LLAVE_PUBLICA"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    }
} else {
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION["LLAVE_ACCESO_WEB"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    $_SESSION["LLAVE_PUBLICA"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
}

?>
```

When the variable `$_SESSION["sesionIniciada"]` doesn't exists, or is false, I destroy the session and create two new variables. No problems there.

In the same page, I have a login form in HTML and when I press the submit button, I call a jquery AJAX function to log in.

This is the function in Javascript:

```
var url = "./app/v1/acceso/web";
var data = JSON.stringify({
    usuario: $.trim($("#usuario").val()),
    clave: $.trim($("#clave").val())
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    headers: {
        'S-Publica': $.trim($("#llave").val()),
        'S-Hash': encriptacion(data, $.trim($("#llave").val())),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function (response){ 
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (e){
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```

I don't have problems with this function, because the request was correct.

The problem is in the PHP file I am calling through AJAX: `var url = "./app/v1/acceso/web"`. On the project directory image is `app/v1/index.php` with a router to the link `/acceso/web`. Inthis file I'm trying to get the `$_SESSION` variables I created in login.php, but They don't exist! It's very strange because all the project is in the same server (and I suppossed it doesn't have problems with the cookie ID).

This is a part of `index.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();

require '../libs/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'mode' => 'debug'
    ));

$app->post('/acceso/web', function () {
    var_dump($_SESSION); //doesn't show the variables session created in login.php
});
```

I don't have idea what is wrong! I'm thinking is the .htaccess file used for Slim, but I don't sure about it! In any case, I publish the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [QSA,L]
```

What's the problem? Thanks!

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

I need to restart session variables after session destroy in `login.php` file:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION) && array_key_exists("sesionIniciada", $_SESSION)) {
    if ($_SESSION["sesionIniciada"] === true) {
        header('Location: /index.php');
    } else {
        session_destroy();
        session_start(); // SOLUTION
        $_SESSION["LLAVE_ACCESO_WEB"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
        $_SESSION["LLAVE_PUBLICA"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    }
} else {
    session_destroy();
    session_start(); // SOLUTION
    $_SESSION["LLAVE_ACCESO_WEB"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
    $_SESSION["LLAVE_PUBLICA"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
}

?>
```

Thanks to Alvaro Montoro for the answer!

Comment: I always thought that you had to call `session_start()` after `session_destroy()` if you wanted to use session variables. Could that be one issue?

Comment: Why are you destroying the session when you're clearly not done with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php:

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie. **To use the session variables
>   again, session_start() has to be called.**

(the bold part is me highlighting what I commented on the question above)

So the solution would be to call `session_start()` after you destroy the session:

```
  session_destroy();
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["LLAVE_ACCESO_WEB"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
  $_SESSION["LLAVE_PUBLICA"] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
```

Comment: And why destroy the session when you're clearly not done with it?

Comment: You'll have to ask @ChristiamMercado about it. It's his code, I just added a `session_start()` :)

Comment: @slime: I destroy the session in `login.php` file  after create the new variables because I need to clean all session variables who I use in other files for login utilities. And about @Alvaro Montoro answer, that's the problem! I don't know I need to start again session variables. Thanks a lot!